# Gentzen's System proved with Hilbert-Ackerman System

Tags: logic

Im trying to proove one of Gentzen's axioms using only the Hilbert Ackerman axioms and deduction rules:

$G2:  (x \rightarrow y ) \rightarrow [(x\rightarrow (y\rightarrow z)) \rightarrow (x\rightarrow z)]$

I've tried a lot of approaches and Im not able to get the complete proof. This is the closest I've gotten to the form.

$A1: (x\rightarrow y ) \rightarrow [(z \lor x)\rightarrow (z \lor y)]$ Hibert-Ackerman 4

$A2:(z\rightarrow y) \rightarrow [((\overline x \lor \overline y) \lor z)\rightarrow (\overline x \lor \overline y \lor y )] $  Substitute $z=\overline x \lor \overline y$ and $x=z$

$A3: (z\rightarrow y) \rightarrow [(x\rightarrow (y\rightarrow z))\rightarrow (x\rightarrow (y\rightarrow y))] $  Abbreviations $\overline x\lor y = x \rightarrow y$

This is the closest I am to G2. Can anyone help me see the missing parts to complete the proof?

Answer (score 0):

The proof is quite complex without intermediate results.

I'll suggest you a "simplified" approach that can be improved.

We have to use the axioms as well as some of the derived rules of David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann's textbook: [Grundzüge der theoretischen Logik](https://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&pg=PA27) (English translation of 1938 second edition), plus of course the *Rule of Implication*.

1) $x \to y$ --- it is $\lnot x \lor y$ rewritten according to abbreviation (page 17)

2) $\lnot x \lor (\lnot y \lor z)$ --- i.e. $x \to (y \to z)$

3) $(\lnot y \lor z) \lor \lnot x$ --- by *commutativity of disjunction*, page 34 (i.e. H&A Ax.c)

4) $y \to (z \lor \lnot x)$ --- Th.16, page 36 and abbreviation

5) $x \to (z \lor \lnot x)$ --- from 1) and 4) by Rule V, page 31

6) $z \lor (\lnot x \lor \lnot x)$ --- as above

7) $x \to z$ --- from 6) and Ax.a by Rule V and abbreviation.

So far we have proved:

> $x \to y, x \to (y \to z) \vdash x \to z$.

H&A system has neither the *Deduction Theorem* nor the concept of "deduction from assumptions".

Thus, we can reformulate the above proof in "H&A-style" as a derived rule (see page 31):

> Rule x. *If* $\mathfrak A \to \mathfrak B$ *is a theorem and* $\mathfrak A \to (\mathfrak B \to \mathfrak C)$ *is a theorem, then* $\mathfrak A \to \mathfrak C$ *is a theorem*.

---

*Note* : why you call it "Gentzen's axiom" ? According to H&A (page 29) we can call it "Frege's axiom" $\text {F2}$.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help. Do you have any reference of the bool you are mentioning? I thought Gentzen had a formal system of 13 axioms (im trying to prove the second lne) which was equivalent to HA. But maybe im wrong here

Comment: I have one more question. I've been able to complete the proof given $x \rightarrow y$ as theorem. But how do I know $x \rightarrow y$ is true? Is there a proof for that?